# errorClass in jquery validate plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using [jquery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin in my web application to validate forms for blank and other simple validations.

I am using below code to setup jquery validate plugin for my form, there is a `erroClass` option in it, where I have defined a CSS class name `authError` which I want to apply on error messages, but its applying the same class to INPUT box as well, I don't want to apply it in INPUT box, just want it for error message. Please check and help. Thanks!

```
$("#frmSignin").validate({
    debug: false,
    errorClass: "authError",
    errorElement: "span",
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
        },
        password: {
            required: true  
        }
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "Please enter your username"
        },
        password: {
            required: "Please enter your password"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks, for the tricks guys, but I instead found a better way by using the jQuery code only. There is a `highlight` event in validate plugin which is called when error occurred to highlight the error fields, I just removed the class form element when this event is called.

```
$("#frmSignin").validate({
    debug: false,
    errorClass: "authError",
    errorElement: "span",
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
        },
        password: {
            required: true  
        }
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "Please enter your username"
        },
        password: {
            required: "Please enter your password"
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You should actually be just defining different classes for input and span (**span** since errorElement is set to span, otherwise it will be **label**), rather than removing the applied class

e.g.

span.authError {color:red;}

input.authError {border:1px dotted red;}

and not just **.authError{}** which will get applied to both input and span

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me. I wish that I came across this post yesterday!

Answer (score 5):

```
    $("#borrowerForm").validate({
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error',
        errorClass: 'field-validation-error',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass(this.settings.errorElementClass).removeClass(errorClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).removeClass(this.settings.errorElementClass).removeClass(errorClass);
        },
        onkeyup: false,
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) { error.insertAfter(element); }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In the jQuery validation plugin, the `errorClass` is both applied to the error message element (usually a `<label>`, but a `<span>` in your case) *and* to the validated element itself. Since you only want to style the error message element, you should write:

```
span.authError {
    // Your error element style.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give css for the error message.
Then in place of using errorClass define css rule

```
label.error
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
$('#frm-contact').validate({
    invalidHandler: function (e, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
                    ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted below'
                    : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted below';
            $("div.error span").html(message);
            $("div.error").show();
        } else {
            $("div.error").hide();
        }
    },
    onkeyup: false,
    submitHandler: function () {
        $("div.error").hide();
        alert("submit! use link below to go to the other step");
    },
    highlight: function (element, required) {
        $(element).fadeOut(function () {
            $(element).fadeIn();
            $(element).css('border', '2px solid #FDADAF');
        });
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).css('border', '1px solid #CCC');
    }
});
```