# How to apply email & phone pattern matching in form validation with JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, validation

this is form validation, it works awesome then how to validate email pattern matching & phone no. matching. Below is my scipt part... Please Help

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true
            },phone: {
                required: true
            },captcha: {
                required: true
            },

        },
        errorPlacement: function(){
            return false;
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            alert('valid form submitted'); 
            return false; 
        }
    });

});
});



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#myform" ).validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                phoneUK: true //or look at the additional-methods.js to see available phone validations
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }

        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your name."                         
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number."                         
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address."                         
            }
        },
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks i already used this... actually here i am using pattern i.e. when field is empty then textbox border color red... all fields work correct... but i want to apply validation in phone no. & email id with pattern matching.. if pattern not match then also shows textbox border color red...

Comment: is this what your looking for :      http://plnkr.co/edit/Nwfk3u2n1YQ6k6X8nyYu?p=preview

Comment: yeh.. actually my code work same as above link... i am unable ta apply pattern matching...

Comment: @sam , Color Apply is Not a part of your Question . You should ask Another question for that ,And if the answer supplies ur requiremet then you shuld do +1

Comment: ya i know... my question is related pattern matching... i just tell what exactly my issue...  @Pranav pls check this   http://plnkr.co/edit/NIFHgkuMQ9hjiwklEsk5?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZK0DkJcIFhpwTSJjUiJ?p=preview  ... I have implemented pattern matching here

Comment: and just saw your code and i just made small changes and its working fine for me now.. http://plnkr.co/edit/g7k5s1wRtAJR0YBrxQwn?p=preview    Do let me know if this what your looking for

Comment: If i want to apply captcha on this & apply validation on captcha.. may u pls provide usefull links...@Pranav...

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("foo", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20}/.test(value);
}, "Your entered data is not phone no");
```

In Function

```
"phone": {
    required: true,
    foo: true
}
```

See: http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Comment: i want to use validation with pattern matching is some like this i.e. when i pattern not match then textbox border color: red otherwise normal.. how can i do...

Comment: @sam refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982957/errorclass-in-jquery-validate-plugin